# Changing the value of comboBox via another controller isn't triggering the onAction callback in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, fxml

Two controllers are there and their respective FXML files.
If I click on the `button` in **View1.fxml**, the value of the comboBox is being changed however I am not getting the output in the console.
But if I click on the `changeValueOfDemoComboBoxBtn` in **View2.fxml**, the output is printed in the console.

**View1.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="120.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**View2.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller2">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="changeValueOfDemoComboBoxBtn" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="264.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleChangeValueOfDemoComboBoxBtnAction" text="Button" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="demoComboBox" layoutX="161.0" layoutY="127.0" onAction="#handleDemoComboBox" prefWidth="150.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller1.java**

```
@FXML
private Button button;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction() throws IOException {

        StackPane contentStackPane = (StackPane)mainScene.lookup("#contentStackPane");

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view2.fxml));
        Parent view2Fxml = loader.load();

        Controller2 controller2 = loader.getController();

        controller2.setDemoComboBox("Apple");

        contentStackPane.getChildren().removeAll();
        contentStackPane.getChildren().setAll(view2Fxml );
}
```

**Controller2.java**

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> demoComboBox;

@FXML
private Button changeValueOfDemoComboBoxBtn;

@FXML
private void handleDemoComboBox() {

        System.out.println("Value changed in Demo ComboBox");
}

@FXML
private void handleChangeValueOfDemoComboBoxBtnAction(){

        setDemoComboBox("Oranges");
}

public void setDemoComboBox(String value){

        demoComboBox.setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: the action is fired by the skin which is set on adding to the scenegraph - so first add the view to the content and then set the value should do the trick (didn't try, though). BTW: no need to remove all children, setAll does so anyway - and fires fewer notification events

Comment: The fact the event doesn't fire before the control is added to a showing window appears to be a bug: [JDK-8087704](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087704).

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the reference - was in solution mode (vs framework cleanup mode :) Indeed, ComboBoxBase specifies to trigger the action whenever the value changes. DatePicker/ComboBox do so only if they have a skin (thus violating their contract without skin), ColorPicker seems to violate the contract always ..